# How should I handle unapproriate situations in C#

Tags: c#

I'm a beginner and haven't had a job yet, so I never work experience with code. 
My question is: 
How should I handle situations, when user enters a value, that doesn't throw exception, but is unacceptable and and program should be closed.
Should I throw an exception with some message in catch block, or it would be enough to just show a message ?

Comment: To help you better, first you need to try something and show us :)

Comment: Keep in mind that there are different approaches for console apps, web apps and UI apps. Unhandled exception in console / UI apps will terminate the application, whereas in web app it would just respond with an error. It is generally better to terminate a program rather than let it continue running under corrupted state.

Comment: This depends a lot on the context: If it's simply a value outside an acceptable range you could just notify the user. If it is a login form subjected to a brute force attack, throwing an exception and/or terminating the program would be the best course.

Comment: I agree that it depends, but it's rarely a good idea to just crash the application because someone made a typo.

Comment: as @kai said this is not good practice to crash the software just becauses user put some invalid input. You must be show error to user to put valid input.

Comment: A Validation Message will be appropriate approach....but it really depends on what you want to achieve...If you running a job then throwing exception might be good approach because you may have system in place which triggers alert emails on exception....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It all depends of You. Depends on what You want to achieve.

There is no ultimate answer to this.

It is good to do everything You said. Throw exeption in `try` `catch` block and then give a information for user and close program.

Additionally log the error with more informataion to a file or databases.

Message box is good, because is user firendly.

Throw exeption is also good because is very readable for developer - when they read You code they see this is a bad sitiation.

For example what to do:

```
    try
    {
       if (IsErrorValidation())
       {
            throw new Exeption("You input wrong data");
       }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      MessageBox.Show("Error" + e.Message );
      CloseProgram();
    }
```

You create new `Exception` with Your massage.

**Better is create Your own type of Exeption for example `ErrorValidationException`** or use the predefined [InvalidArgumentException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.common.invalidargumentexception%28v=sql.120%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) which exist in C#

```
        try
        {
           if (IsErrorValidation())
           {
                throw new ErrorValidationException("You input wrong data");
           }
        }
        catch (ErrorValidationException e)
        {
          MessageBox.Show("Error" + e.Message);
          CloseProgram();
        }
        catch (Exeption e)
        {  
           ...
        }
```

Then You can use this type of exception later and You can serve this type of exception in a different way

Answer (score 3):

Its really up to the requirements of the application that you are developing. But c# has a specific exception type for this:

[InvalidArgumentException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.common.invalidargumentexception(v=sql.120).aspx)

And you can use it like this:

```
if (!ValidateUserInput(input))
    throw new InvalidArgumentException ("input is invalid");
```

You can then catch that further up in the application and decide how to handle it